# Suppress 'author' field when 'useauthor=false' in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I would like to prevent `biblatex` from printing `by (name of author)` in the bibliography in only those cases where I have put `OPTIONS = "useauthor=false"` in the entry in the `.bib` file. I assume I can put a relatively straightforward command in my `.tex` preamble that will take care of this. Below a silly example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
        bibstyle = authoryear,
        citestyle = authoryear-comp,
        sorting = nyt,
        language = american,
        abbreviate = false,
        backend = biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{bible,
    AUTHOR = "God",
    EDITOR = "James, King",
    TITLE = "The {H}oly {B}ible",
    YEAR = "1611",
    OPTIONS = "useauthor=false, useeditor=true"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Text \parencite{bible}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a bunch of ways you might do this; but a simple one (that doesn't involve fiddling with the bibliography drivers at all) is just to clear the `author` field if `useauthor` if false:

```
\AtEveryCitekey{\ifuseauthor{}{\clearname{author}}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\ifuseauthor{}{\clearname{author}}}
```

Answer (score 6):

Redefine the `byauthor` bibmacro to do nothing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
        bibstyle = authoryear,
        citestyle = authoryear-comp,
        sorting = nyt,
        language = american,
        abbreviate = false,
        backend = biber]{biblatex}
\renewbibmacro*{byauthor}{}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{bible,
    AUTHOR = "God",
    EDITOR = "James, King",
    TITLE = "The {H}oly {B}ible",
    YEAR = "1611",
    OPTIONS = "useauthor=false, useeditor=true"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Text \parencite{bible}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Compare the original version of `byauthor`:

```
\newbibmacro*{byauthor}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseauthor
    or
    test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{author}{author}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[byauthor]{author}}}
```

Comment: Since this doesn't refer to `"useauthor=false"`, will this have no unwanted consequences for other bibliographical entries?

Comment: @Sverre `byauthor` itself refers to the state of `useauthor`.

Comment: Great, thanks. Since I can accept only one answer, I accepted Paul's, because I understood it right away.